# How do I execute a powershell script via group policy?

Tags: group-policy, scripting, powershell

How can I execute a powershell script by means of group policy on a number of machines?

The script is signed and will run on the targeted machines when you right-click and select "run with powershell".

Comment: Do you want to run the script as a computer startup script? Or do you want to run the script on-demand?

Comment: startup script please

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx

In particular, I think you'd want to edit your machine start up GPO to run:

> C:\windows\system32\windowspowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe &
>   "C:\script.ps1"

The path to PowerShell.exe does not change if you have v1 or v2 installed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-) 

The script still does NOT start from group policy but will start if pasted into the run box when the machine is booted: 
"C:\windows\system32\windowspowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit & '\\servername.local\SysVol\servername.local\Policies\{D6A8EB7C-38B0-44B8-AE81-AB6B3E7D8DB0}\User\Scripts\Logon\UpdateDesktopWithBGInfo.ps1'"

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: Is this a computer start up or user log on script? If the former, you'd need to make sure the machine account has access to the network location. I'm not sure what would cause the latter to not work. Maybe replace the PowerShell bit with a simple .bat file or something like that so that you know the script is able to run. 
That way you'll know if your problem is with calling the script, or getting to the script in the first place.

Comment: Another option would be to use another GPO to push the script to the local computer and execute it from there.

Comment: how have you determined that it does not run at all, as opposed to running and failing before it can have any effect?

Comment: Something like this would do the trick: 
`echo "test" > "%userprofile%\desktop\test.txt"`
that's a .BAT file on the scripts tab, not on the PowerShell tab.

Comment: - how would i push the GPO to the local computer? 
- I added a simple line to script to write a file to "C:\temp\dir.txt".  i thought this would be a good test to see if the script is running but i guess this could fail as well.  Any recomendations to see how i test the script is working
- I dont have the powershell tab. I'm using SBS 2008 (Windows 2008 and not the R2 version).  I'll give the bat file ago.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: push files to computers in GPO: Computer Configuration - Preferences - Windows Settings - Files.

Comment: if you are writing to C:\, make sure you have permission to do so. That's why I used the %userprofile% variable.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution (what I did) to bginfo:

1. Set up a user logon GPO (User Configuration - Policies - Windows
   Settings - Scripts)
2. Under the Scripts tab (not PowerShell), click
   show files, and copy bginfo.exe and your .bgi configuration file
3. Go back to the Scripts tab, click add, enter "bginfo.exe" for Script Name, and "desktopSettings.bgi /timer:0 /nolicprompt" for Script Parameters.

Make sure you do gpupdate /force and logoff/logon, then you should see bginfo on your desktop.

Comment: I want to get powershell working because i have other uses for powershell.  I thought this would be a simple script to start with.  Thanks